# JFactory::getSession() in module, produces a 500 error

Tags: module, joomla-api, joomla-3.5

I am trying to get the JSession inside my module php file.

But every time I wrote this code:

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
```

Joomla responds with a 500 error for the page that my module is loaded.

If I comment out that line, the page is loading again fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this the only reference to the session you're using? Are you using something like `$session->set('something', 'something');` anywhere else?

Comment: No I don't use other reference, but I think I figured out what the problem is. I have later in my code a print_r($session) which seems to create the issue. I guess I must use something like print_r($session->getData()).

Answer (score 2):

I think I found out my mistake that causes the error.

I have later in my code a:

```
print_r($session);
```

and this is actually the code that is generating the 500 error.

I must use something like:

```
print_r($session->getData());
```

to print out the session data.

Comment: no, you 100% don't. I mean this isn't causing issues. Used this many times.

Comment: @Alexandr: In my case, everytime I tried to use that in that site and on another test site, I got a 500error. Removing the print_r($session) site works.

Comment: well I think it's something with your server then)